# CMake OBJECT library + MinGW not linkng

Tags: cmake, mingw, qmake, object-files, ninja

I'm builds my static library using CMake and ninja. Static library builds from several [CMake OBJECT libraries](https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake/Tutorials/Object_Library).

And I'm builds executable using qmake and MinGW (4.92, 32bit).

The Problem is, resulting static library not linking with executable. All functions from object libaries is undefined reference.

Without using ninja this problem not reproduces.

Answer (score 1):

This is CMake's bug. Fixed in 3.4 version. 
https://cmake.org/Bug/view.php?id=15729